# Trying to get value from table on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="table" id = "posts_table">

  <caption><h2>cars</h2></caption>
  <tr class="success">
    <th style="text-align:center"> post_id 
    <th style="text-align:center"> autor 
    <th style="text-align:center"> title 
  </tr>
  <?php 
    $cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE topic_id=:topic_id");
    $cursor->execute( array(":topic_id"=>"1") ); //לשנות
    foreach ($cursor->fetchAll() as $obj): ?>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"><? echo $obj['post_id'] ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><? echo $obj['full_name']?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><a href="post.php#"><? echo $obj['post_title']?></a></td>
    </tr>
  <? endforeach; ?>    
</table
```

I want to create function that when u click on the title im getting the `post_id` for this raw. What should I do to make it happen?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to just post a "write all the code for me" question on SO. If you include the code you've tried and a description of what isn't working, you're much more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: Do you want it to return the post_id when you click on the title? Not too sure what is being asked x:

Answer (score 0):

So i try to do this code and it works:

```
<table class="table" id = "posts_table">

            <caption><h2>cars</h2></caption>
            <tr class="success">
                <th style="text-align:center"> post_id </th>
                <th style="text-align:center"> autor </th>
                <th style="text-align:center"> title </th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE topic_id=:topic_id");
                $cursor->execute( array(":topic_id"=>"1") ); //לשנות
                foreach ($cursor->fetchAll() as $obj): ?>
            <tr>
                 <td class="post_id_c" style="text-align:center"><? echo $obj['post_id'] ?></td>
                 <td style="text-align:center"><? echo $obj['full_name']?></td>
                 <td style="text-align:center"><a class="click_title"><? echo $obj['post_title']?></a></td>
            </tr>
                <? endforeach; ?>    
          </table> 
          <script>
              $(".click_title").click(function() {
                        var $item = $(this).closest("tr")   // Finds the closest row <tr> 
                       .find(".post_id_c")     // Gets a descendent with class="nr"
                       .text(); 
                  console.log($item);
              });
            
          </script>
```